# What is mapping fiber channel upon install of 14.04?

Tags: io, iscsi, multipath

We installed 14.04 that is connected to a fiber channel.  I was expecting to wrestle with multipath to get the LUNs connected, but I noticed that I am mounted to the fiber channel right after install.

What process is doing this out of the box?

Answer (score 0):

It's part of your initrd and the multipathd should also be running at startup. So if you do end up changing your multipath.conf be sure to rebuild your ramdisk so the file is copied there as well. Otherwise weird race conditions can occur once you try to add LVM to the mix.

https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/multipath-devices.html

Comment: Sorry for the late response here.  When I look, multipathd is not running on the box as a process.  I'm assuming this is running from the kernel somehow (as a kernel driver)?

Comment: @jasonmclose The daemon is needed to perform failover, not to create the maps.  You can literally just run "multipath" once to create the maps. The maps are built while the system is still in the initrd using udev. 

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/multipath-tools/wily/view/head:/debian/initramfs/local-top